# Additional directory name issue when ASP.NET MVC site is deployed to IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment, devops

I have created a ASP.Net MVC site. In the views I use JQuery data table to display records. Also, I use Ajax calls to get data to show in the web views. Also I have a image background set in the _Layouts.cshtml. This all worked fine in the developers machines. Accessed the site using http://localhost:portnumber format.

Now the site has been deployed to a UAT environment at clients end. It seems the devops guys have deployed it as a microsite/as a new directory in a existing site. The URL I get to see looks like http://companysitename/ANameGivenToMyApplication

Now The background image does not load.
The Ajax calls to the controllers does not work, hence data does not get loaded to the JQuery data table view.

I tried to capture the "ANameGivenToMyApplication" part n the url, by using various way but no luck.
The results are as below:

```
window.location.origin > http://companysitename 
window.location.host > companysitename 
window.location.hostname > companysitename 
window.location.pathname > ANameGivenToMyApplication/MyController/Index 
window.location.href > http://companysitename/ANameGivenToMyApplication/MyController/Index
```

Seems like if this "ANameGivenToMyApplication" part (which probably is a directory name) is not there in the URL anymore the issues go away.

How can I avoid this deployment issue (or rather way of deployment) affect the whole web application which I have developed?

--UPDATED--

The DevOps guys have added the site as a "Application" within a existing web site in IIS
[image]

Comment: you could try to use the iis URL rewrite rule and rewrite the URL or the link reference.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal thank you for your reply. I am not aware of the URL rewrite rule. Could you please give me an idea on how to do that ?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal It seems the site is hosted within a "Application" in side the web application in IIS. Is there a way to get that path in the code ? in Javascript or JQuery ?

Comment: could you share the iis site structure screenshot?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal included the image in the description above